# CS50P, Problem Set 4: Little Professor - Difficulty in Figuring Out the Error

Tags: python, cs50

I am learning Python via Harvard's CS50 and I am having difficulty in developing a program as described here: https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/4/professor/. The code I've come up with works as expected with all the tests I run through it; however, it fails several *check50* tests. Specifically, I get the errors described here: https://submit.cs50.io/check50/241b21748cb55a00e77338eff5aca0e7e3f3a0e1.

[image: Image in case link doesn't work]

Should I hardcode a response that's being expected? I'm not understanding how "Level: X + Y =" is being returned instead of just "X + Y = ".

Here is my code:

```
import random


def main():
    random.seed()

    listOperand1 = []
    listOperand2 = []

    nLevel = get_level()

    for i in range(10):
        listOperand1.append(generate_integer(nLevel))
        listOperand2.append(generate_integer(nLevel))

    nScore = 0

    for i in range(10):
        nAttempts = 3

        while nAttempts > 0:
            try:
                nAnswer = int(input(f"{listOperand1[i]} + {listOperand2[i]} = "))
            except ValueError:
                nAttempts -= 1
                print("EEE")
                continue
            finally:
                if nAttempts == 0:
                    print(
                        f"{listOperand1[i]} + {listOperand2[i]} = {listOperand1[i]+listOperand2[i]}"
                    )
                    break

            if nAnswer == (listOperand1[i] + listOperand2[i]):
                nScore += 1
                break
            else:
                nAttempts -= 1
                print("EEE")

    print(f"Score: {nScore}")


def get_level():
    while True:
        try:
            nLevel = int(input("Level: ").strip())

            if nLevel in [1, 2, 3]:
                return nLevel
            else:
                continue
        except ValueError:
            continue


def generate_integer(level):
    if level == 1:
        return random.randint(0, 9)
    elif level == 2:
        return random.randint(10, 99)
    elif level == 3:
        return random.randint(100, 999)
    else:
        raise ValueError


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It is odd that it's looking for the **specific** question `6 + 6 =`, when the digits are supposed to be random.  I assume the `Level:` output is coming from the input prompt where the user chooses the level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest removing `random.seed()`. It interferes with the testing black box that is check50.